# Transaction allow to fail and continue

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, transactions, rollback

Im having a problem with a major data migration that can be configured by the user, lets say it goes like this:

```
try {
    daoManager.beginTransaction();

    for (Entity node : nodeList) {

        boolean inserted;

        if (migrationConfig.canInsert()) {
            try {
                inserted = daoManager.getDaoEntity().insert(node);
            }
            catch(IndexDuplicityException ex) {
                inserted = false;
                //I want the transaction to continues when this Exceptions is
                //throwed
            }
        }

        if (migrationConfig.canUpdate() && !inserted) {
            modificoEntidad = daoManager.getDaoEntity().update(node);
        }
    }

    //Later

    if (//Business Logic) {
        throw new MustRollBackTransaction();
    }

    daoManager.commitTransaction();

} catch (MustRollBackTransaction ex) {
    daoManager.RollBack();
}
```

My problem is that when the IndexDuplicityException is throwed, any of the future transactions are ignored, giving me this exception

> PSQLException: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until
>   end of transaction block

Isnt there a way to my transaction allow failed excecuted statements and not abort the whole transaction?

Thanks.

Comment: Does Postgres support exception tables where constraint violations are written to ? This might suppress the exception which marks the transaction as rollback only.

Comment: @Nicholas could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rollback the transaction and start a new one on IndexDuplicityException:

```
   }catch(IndexDuplicityException ex) {
    inserted = false;       
    daoManager.RollBack();
    daoManager.beginTransaction();
   }
```

Comment: If I do this I will lose all previous executed statements.

Comment: @leomcpugo And what about setting a savepoint each iteration and if the exception occurs you rollback to it?

Comment: I guess that should do it! Thanks!